# Mysql : Trying to get all Child node of tree

Tags: mysql, treeview

Not getting solution to create complete tree in one call of mysql procedure or query by passing root node.

I have a table with below structure -

```
CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
  `login` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agent_account` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`));
```

Here agent_account is reference of login. 
By Following this reference i can generate a tree.

[Here is image of table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1OW9.png)

```
select login from ( select * from user_accounts order by agent_account, login) Folder, 
   (select @pv := '13259355') initialisation 
     where find_in_set(agent_account, @pv) > 0 
    and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', login )
```

Not getting expected result which will give all nodes of a tree.

Comment: I fail to see why it's expected to get all the nodes